# Unity Bot AI behaviour

Tags: unity, unityscript, bot

I'm working in Unity3d 2019.2.0f1 and I'm trying to make a chasing bot that follows a certain `GameObject` with the "Player" tag.

I'm not yet attempting a field of view approach.

How the Script works:

Step 1 : Overlap a sphere on the Bot AI's `transform.position` and put all the things in the sphere inside a `Collider[]`.

Step 2: Go through each `collider` in ColliderArray and look for a `GameObject` with the tag "Player".

Step 3: If found shoot a `Raycast` to said `GameObject` with tag.

Step 4: If the Gameobject hit does not have the "Player" tag, then the "Player" is being blocked by a obstacle therefor not in the line of sight,
if the `GameObject` isn't blocked by an obstacle then we set the destination of the referenced `Navmeshagent`.

The problem I'm finding (with about 3000 Debug.Logs) is that the `Raycast` only shoots around 7 times and then just stops, also the "Player" needs to stand in a very specific random location (even tho the "Player" is in plane sight).

What am I doing wrong here?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    NavMeshAgent agent;

    public float LookRadius = 20; //unity units

    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, LookRadius);

        foreach(Collider Object in colliders)
        {
            if(Object.transform.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                RaycastHit hit;

                if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Object.transform.position, out hit, Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Object.transform.position)))
                {
                    //if not true the we hit a obstacle.
                    if(hit.transform.CompareTag("Player"))
                    {
                        agent.SetDestination(hit.transform.position);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so, in your line of code "if(physics.Raycast(transform.position," etc.what exactly are you doing?  (I don't understand raycast code very well, but I've never seen it written like that.)

Comment: When you do a raycast in an if statement it carries on when you hit something. it does exactly the same otherwise

Comment: ok, is the vector 3 calculating the distance between the raycast point and the player?

Comment: No the vector3.Distance calculates the distance between the Bot and the player, therefor the raycast will be the perfect length

Comment: one thing that confuses me, is that you have a comment that says //if not true that we hit a obstacle.   but the line under that doesn't seem to check whether you hit an obstacle, it seems to check whether the object you hit is the player.

Comment: Yeah, so if the raycast dident hit anything we don't do anything, if we did hit something we check if what we hit is an obstacle using tag.

Comment: ok, so just to recap, the script has an array of all the colliders that come within the radius of 20, the bot then sends a raycast to all those colliders, then if the raycast hits nothing, that means something is in the line of view, so the bot will do nothing, and if it  hits something, the bot checks if it is the player, and if so, it set's it's target to the player position.  is that right?

Comment: Sort of, the script "Loops" throw all the collider in said radius and only if it find the "Player" tag will it send a raycast to the said Player. and if what that raycast hit also has a "player" tag will it set the target to the player position, if the thing the raycast hits does not have the "Player" tag then it is an obstacle therefor the Bot's line of sight is blocked

Comment: Not sure what's going on, the codes seems correct to me, but i'm not an expert on raycasts.  You said that  the "Player" needs to stand in a very specific random location (even tho the "Player" is in plane sight).  Are you saying that the raycast only works if the player is in a specific location?

Comment: Yes. for some reason

Comment: That is weird!  I don't see why that would happen. I suppose it _could_ be the Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Object.transform.position))).  I don't know if that could cause such a weird bug or not, but it's just an idea.

Comment: mmmhhhhh, i`ll look into it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) the second parameter of `Physics.Raycast` (in the shape you're using) is a direction, not a position. So you have to compute the direction where you want to cast your ray from the agent.

You can get the direction by `(target.position - transform.position).normalized`.

Also, for optimization sake (not related to your question), it appears that the `OverlapSphere` call that you're doing is not necessary. You have probably a way to get the Players transforms in your code (via a singleton pattern or something else). Doing so you would avoid looping on every single object that contains a collider and that is around your agent. A simple call to `Vector3.Distance()` would be necessary to know if the player is close enough of your agent. Looping on every colliders of your scene for every agent would be overkill imho.

Comment: Thanks! your solution worked perfectly. i will also take into account the performance tips.